# Create a list from another list

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say I have:

```
class Plus5 {
    Plus5(int i) {
         i+5;
     }
}
List<int> initialList = [0,1,2,3]
```

How I can create, from `initialList`, another list calling `Plus5()` constructor for each element of initialList.

Is here something better than the following?

```
List<Plus5> newList = new List<Plus5>();
initialList.ForEach( i => newList.Add(Plus5(int)));
```

Comment: yep, i am building a list of Plus5 from a initial list of int

Comment: Is there a reason you want to have a `Plus5` type?  It sounds like you may just want to build a new list of `int` where the `ints` happen to be incremented by 5

Comment: its just for the example

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use LINQ to add 5 to each number in your list.

```
var result = initialList.Select(x => x + 5);
```

Comment: Great, i didnt realized that Select got that power.

Comment: Have a look at this link http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b. Its a great starting place for learning LINQ.

Answer (score 23):

> How i can create, from initialList, another list calling Plus5()
>   constructor for each element of initialList?

So the result is `List<Plus5> newList` and you want to create a new `Plus5` for every `int` in `initialList`:

```
List<Plus5> newList = initialList.Select(i => new Plus5(i)).ToList();
```

If you want to micro-optimize(save memory):

```
List<Plus5> newList = new List<Plus5>(initialList.Count);
newList.AddRange(initialList.Select(i => new Plus5(i)));
```

Comment: This is a correct answer.  However, you may want to suggest an alternative solution where he can create a `List<int>` such that the `ints` happen to be incremented by 5 :)

Comment: @steaks: It seems as if roughnex has already posted that approach(at least `IEnumerable<int>`). However, it is not what OP has asked for.

Comment: Yeah, thats the correct answer. Thanks you, the +5 were just for the example :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ as roughnex mentioned.

```
var result = initialList.Select(x => x + 5).ToList();
```

If you had a method (like Plus5), it would look like so

```
int Plus5(int i)
{
    return I + 5;
}

var result = initialList.Select(Plus5).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Plus5> result = new List<Plus5>(InitialList.Select(x=>new Plus5(x)).ToList()));
```

Comment: This won't even compile. You are trying to construct a `List<int>` by passing in `List<Plus5>` as a constructor parameter.